# Error in eclipse, which does not occur outside the eclipse (using maven, strut2, hibernate4, spring3)

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven, struts2

I am developing a project with maven, strut2, hibernate4, spring3 and eclipse
The application works perfectly when I copy the file ".War" to a install external of tomcat (Apache Tomcat Version 7.0.21), it is a installation of xampp.

That is, the following process is working properly:
"Run as" -> "Maven install"
Copy the file ".War" located in the folder "target" of the project
Paste the file in the folder
"Tomcat \ webapps"
Run the tomcat

The problem arises when I try to run the application from the eclipse to:

- Save time
- Debug the application
- Work in a more comfortable environment

I always get the following exception:

```
    2012-09-11 13:02:41,853 ERROR [ContextLoader.java:215] : Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in file [D:\Dropbox\web\mis proyectos\maven\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\WIMP\WEB-INF\classes\applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:259)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    ... 25 more
sep 11, 2012 1:02:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in file [D:\Dropbox\web\mis proyectos\maven\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\WIMP\WEB-INF\classes\applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/annotations/common/reflection/MetadataProvider
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:259)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.MetadataProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    ... 25 more
```

It is an exception that apparently corresponds to Hibernate3, although the application uses hibernate4

Besides that particularly bothers me when I do not use the eclipse the error does not occur, and using the eclipse itself (Tomcat v7.0 Server).

```
applicationContext.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Example of SAF2 action instantiated by Spring -->
    <bean id="helloWorldAction" class="org.com.WIMP.HelloWorldAction" scope="prototype"/>

    <!-- The singleton hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" scope="singleton" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Spring's hibernate transaction manager, in charge of making hibernate sessions/txns -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- So classes/functions with @Transactional get a hibernate txn -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Inject my business services class to the actions --><!-- services.Services -->
    <bean id="services" class="org.com.WIMP.services.Services" scope="singleton">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>


pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>WIMP</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
    <name>Struts 2 Starter</name>
    <url>http://www.myComp.com</url>
    <description>Struts 2 Starter</description>

    <properties>
        <struts2.version>${project.version}</struts2.version>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Struts 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-sitemesh-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${struts2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- cglib -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet & Jsp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jakarta Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dwr -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.ltd.getahead</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-beta-3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
              <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <finalName>WIMP</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                   <source>1.5</source>
                   <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.21</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <scanTargets>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/resources/struts.xml</scanTarget>
                        <scanTarget>src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml</scanTarget>
                    </scanTargets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                        <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If you can help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: maybe your dependencies are not getting copied to the WEB-INF/lib folder of wtp. can you check Right Click on project -> Properties -> Deployment Assembly. there should be an entry like this: Maven Dependencies -> WEB-INF/lib

Comment: I have 5 entries
/src/main/java  =>    WEB-INF/classes;
/src/main/resources         =>    WEB-INF/classes; 
/src/main/java                    =>    /; 
/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources =>    /; 
Maven Dependencies              =>    WEB-INF/lib;

Comment: doubleclick on the server in eclipse, copy the Server path value (Server Locations) and follow the path in your explorer (it is relative to your workspace). find the WEB-INF/lib folder and check whether hibernate-commons-annotations-x.x.x.jar is present.

Comment: the file is not in the folder, actually has 10 unless the folder files generated by the ".war". 

know how you can configure the eclipse to load it properly, or rather introduce the libraries manually each time you change the file ".pom"


thank you very much

Comment: do you use m2eclipse (eclipse plugin)? does the project build in eclipse (without errors)? have you already tried a Project->Clean, or Right-Click on the server->Clean? can you post your .classpath file?

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was that I hadn't done on the server "clean"

Always had in the project: "maven clean", "maven install", "maven buid", etc.

now it's working right running on eclipse